# Search Twitter for Tweets Containing Polls

Tags: twitter, twitter-api, twitter-search

I'm trying to figure out a way to use Twitter Advanced Search to find **only** tweets containing polls.

Ideally, there should have been a designated **filter** operator like **filter:polls** but it doesn't exist.

Any ideas on how to do it in another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going off Joost C's answer, here's a link that searches all of those at once using OR's:

https://twitter.com/search?q=card_name%3Apoll2choice_text_only%20OR%20card_name%3Apoll3choice_text_only%20OR%20card_name%3Apoll4choice_text_only%20OR%20card_name%3Apoll2choice_image%20OR%20card_name%3Apoll3choice_image%20OR%20card_name%3Apoll4choice_image

Here's the same, but filtered to people you follow ("pf=on" query parameter):

https://twitter.com/search?q=card_name%3Apoll2choice_text_only%20OR%20card_name%3Apoll3choice_text_only%20OR%20card_name%3Apoll4choice_text_only%20OR%20card_name%3Apoll2choice_image%20OR%20card_name%3Apoll3choice_image%20OR%20card_name%3Apoll4choice_image&pf=on

Comment: These links work for me, but unfortunately I can only see 10 days’ worth of results. An example from the wonderful (departed?) WYR_bot: https://twitter.com/search?q=card_name%3Apoll2choice_text_only%20from%3Awyr_bot&f=live

Answer (score 6):

To find polls containing 2, 3 or 4 choices, either text or image polls, use:

```
card_name:poll2choice_text_only

card_name:poll3choice_text_only

card_name:poll4choice_text_only

card_name:poll2choice_image

card_name:poll3choice_image

card_name:poll4choice_image
```

Source: https://github.com/igorbrigadir/twitter-advanced-search